# Should I use ThreadLocal to store connections?

Tags: java, servlets

I code my Test project and it is prohibited to use Spring and Hibernate there.

I wanted to manage my transactions from Service layer.
For this I have created a class that gets a Connection from the pool and puts it in the ThreadLocal.

This is an example of the fields and the method.

```
  private static ThreadLocal<Connection> threadLocalConnection;
  private ComboPooledDataSource comboPooledDataSource ;

  public boolean createConnectionIfAbsent() {

    boolean isConnectionCreated = false;

    try {
      Connection currentConnection = threadLocalConnection.get();
      if(currentConnection == null) {
        Connection conn = this.comboPooledDataSource.getConnection();
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        threadLocalConnection.set(conn);
        isConnectionCreated = true;
      }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return isConnectionCreated;
  }
```

The class has also close, rollback methods.

Here is the example of how I manage Connections in a Service Layer.

```
public BigDecimal getTotalOrdersCount() {
    boolean connectionCreated = DBManager.getInstance().createConnectionIfAbsent();

    BigDecimal ordersCount = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    try {
        ordersCount = orderDao.getRowNumber();
    } catch (SQLException throwables) {
        throwables.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (connectionCreated) DBManager.getInstance().closeConnection();
    }
    return ordersCount;
}
```

Dao just uses this to get the connection.

```
Connection connection = DBManager.getInstance().getConnection();
```

I found no other way to manage connections in a Servlet project from a Service layer, could you please tell if it is ok? If not - what drawbacks does it have and what should I use instead.

**UPD:**

Please pay attention to this Service method. Let's assume that Each method in DAO gets the Connection from a pool and closes it.
I do know that I need connection.setAutoCommit(false); to start a transaction, but what to do it in this kind of a situation?
When a single methods calls 2 DAO.
Just give up on a transaction handling?

```
void setStatusDeclinedAndRefund() {
// sets Order status to DECLINED
// refund money to user's balance
}
```

Comment: No one else is doing this. We all just let the connection pool sort out which connection gets used. Why do you need to keep a reference to a connection in ThreadLocal?

Comment: Seems like too broad a scope for your connections. You should get a connection for a task/job and close it when the task is done. I'd just keep the reference to connection pool and get/close connection from it in a try with resources.

Comment: @Bohemian Because I need to perform transactions from a service layer.
For example, If I need to call 2 DAOs from a Service method. In a normal code each DAO method opens a Connection and closes it, it seems like there would be no transaction.
I would appreciate it so much if you could tell me what to use instead and what drawbacks does the code above have

Comment: @ernest_k Does this mean that it is better to give up on transactions and just use regular calls to dao?
For example, there is a service method declineOrderAndRefund that calls 2 different DAO methods, will giving up on transactions be a mistake in such a scenario?
If yes, what should I use in a Service to be able to manage transactions?

Comment: Before I comment further, I'd strongly urge you to look into some kind of design methodology, such as domain-driven-design. As you have things here, responsibility for managing persistence-related objects is widespread across your call chains, and that's an open door for bugs.

Comment: @mark so what? Everything that needs a connection gets one from the pool, uses it (with a transaction or not), then closes it (which actually just releases it back to the pool). You're overthinking it. See [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/java-connection-pooling).

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by *transaction*. It could just be that `autoCommit = false` flag on your connections... That's irrelevant to my comment. The first challenge I see with this is that connections are managed by business methods. You could forget, there could be a sneaky error somewhere, but your code is not the one managing threads (or servlet instances on which connection objects are cached, and reused from). This kind of creativity requires too much attention to details and to specifications, which raises a question against such decisions as "no hibernate"...

Comment: btw there is no such thing as *prohibited*. Whomever has mandated that should be ignored; use whatever library is the best fit for the task.

Comment: @ernest_k I've updated the question, could you please pay attention to UPD part.

Comment: @Mark_Daniels that makes no difference. There are plenty of strategies and tools to manage transactions involving multiple services with no need of low-level handling of connections and threads. You don't need to implement a transaction management system in 2022.

Comment: @ernest_k could you please share a strategy to do this, I can find none :(

Comment: @ThiloSchwarz thank you for answering, I did not tell that. I use servlets only and Spring is prohibited :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Don't second guess the connection pool. Use it in the standard way: get a connection, use it, close it.

There is no need to use the same connection for every database interaction in a given thread. Also, you'll have serious liveliness problems if you allocate each thread a connection, because typically there are way more request processing threads than there are connections in the pool.

Comment: Thank you,I've updated the question, could you please pay attention to UPD part.
I am new to Servlets and learned Spring first, so would appreciate your help a lot.
P.S. Tried to solve this problem myself for weeks.

Comment: @Mark_Daniels I don't understand your problem. Get a connection, set auto commit to false, run query 1 with it, run query 2 with it, commit, close.

Comment: I have 2 DAO methods that are used everywhere in the program.
Now I need to use both of them in one method. 
Should I repeat myself and create a third DAO method that just copy-pastes 2 previous with the connection.setAutoCommit(false) just to execute them in a transaction?

Or maybe there is a better way so they can be called with a transaction from a service?